# How to remove a repeating sequence from a string - php

Tags: php

I have a function written by someone else which returns the address of a customer. This function isn't as simple as you would have thought it might need to be. For a good reason it has been written so that the return variable goes through:

```
eval("\$address_out = \"$fmt\";");
```

first. And despite a quick look in the manual just what it does it a mystery to me. So the problem is the address is returned like these two examples (note on has 3 repeating `<br/>`s and the other 4)

```
ginger rogers<br /> hollywood<br /> California<br /> <br /> <br /> United states

ginger rogers<br /> hollywood<br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> United states
```

I thought it would be quicker to just strip the repeating `<br/>`s out but I'm confused because there can be a different amount of them and they are seperated by spaces.

Anyone any ideas?

EDIT: I should have said, I want to keep one of the 
 between each bit of the address, it's where there are multipul 
 I want to get rid of all but one

Comment: Use [`strip_tags()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)

Comment: There's hardly ever a good reason for `eval`. I'm also not sure what that has to do with the second part of the question.

Comment: @jackflash - I forgot to say, I want to keep one of the <br/>s between each part of the address. Just removing multipul ones which screw up my layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$addr = str_replace( array( '<br/>', '<br>', '<br />', "\r", "\n" ), '', $addr );` will remove `<br/>` breaks, plus new line and carriage return characters.

To maintain one `<br/>` still:

```
while ( strpos( $addr, '<br /> <br />' ) !== false ) { 
    // while two adjoining <br />'s still exist in the variable
    // replace two with one <br /> break
    $addr = str_replace( '<br /> <br />', '<br />', $addr );
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but I want to keep one <br/> each time. I just don't want multipul <br/>s

Comment: Oh I see! Edited to accommodate.